# Request to a post request of web service returns HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: web-services, rest, http, jersey, http-error

I have made a POST web service which has three path params.

But when i try to request this web service through url, i get HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

But the same method works, if i change the web service to @GET

```
@POST
@Path("/authCode/{code}/{token}/{secret}")
public Response getToken(@PathParam("code") String code,@PathParam("token") String token,@PathParam("secret") String secret) {

    String output = code;
    System.out.println("code output"+output);

    System.out.println("********A basic user profile call into a subresource return data in JSON********"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    String url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/summary";
```

Request URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/SocialNetwork/rest/linkedin/authCode/17842/81--sdfsdf-8a57-adfd-9ddb-dfdddfdf/sdfsdfsd-fb54-402d-9a85-dsfdsfsdf
```

This is the response i get

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.78 - Error report</title>
    <style>
        <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed</h1>
    <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
    <p>
        <b>type</b> Status report
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>message</b>
        <u>Method Not Allowed</u>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>description</b>
        <u>The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.</u>
    </p>
    <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
    <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.78</h3>
</body>
```

Any Help will be grateful!!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the server does not allow `POST` methods. Only `GET` methods are allowed. **405 Method Not Allowed** indicates this.

To get the `POST` request to work, you need to enable a `POST` request method in the headers of the HTTP request on the server. You can usually do this simply by adding an endpoint for such a call.

For example, your code may look like this for the `GET` request:

```
router.GET('/some-endpoint', someGETHandlerFunc)
```

To enable the same endpoint for `POST`, you would add:

```
router.POST('/some-endpoint', somePOSTHandlerFunc)
```

Together:

```
router.GET('/some-endpoint', someGETHandlerFunc)
router.POST('/some-endpoint', somePOSTHandlerFunc)
```

---

**Now to your question...**

Your request endpoint does not match the `POST` endpoint.

The `POST` endpoint as indicated in your question is:

```
/authCode/{code}/{token}/{secret}
```

Your request URL you provided does not match that, as it has `/SocialNetwork/rest/linkedin/` prepended to it. Unless your decorator in the server endpoint prepends this as well, that is probably your error.

Comment: thanks for your reply

/SocialNetwork/rest/linkedin/ is whole path defined for my java project

SocialNetwork- my java project
rest- defined in web.xml
linkedin- my endpoint to enter in the class where my method is defined
and authcode- my endpoint for the method, 

so the whole url i mentioned works correctly for every other web service created in that package. but its only the POST method which is not working

Comment: Just to throw it out there..have you tried restarting the server? I'm now sure how Java development is, but if you are running an executable then I'd imagine you need to rebuild and execute it again after making the change. Make sure you haven't forgotten this.

Comment: Also try to make another `POST` endpoint and see if you can hit it. If you can, there is a problem with the code above. If you can't, the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Yes that worked, cleaned the project, cleaned tomcat working directory and it worked then,

What a drag, such simple it was and it took me hours determine :P

Comment: Haha nice! That is software development in a nutshell :). I've spent days on typos that were not caught by a code error.